# Suppressing confirmation on Remove-Item WITHOUT using -recurse

Tags: powershell

So I want to delete top level directories based on creation date.  I don't want my script to consider ANY dates below that (e.g. my top level folder might be 31 days old, whereas subdirectories may be newer - but I still want the whole top level directory removed along with everything in it - I only care about the top level folder's creation date.  Thus I don't want to use `-recurse`.  However, I keep getting prompted with the whole "the folder has subdirectories do you want to continue...blah blah".  Can't have that.  How can I suppress this without using `-recurse`?  I've tried `Remove-Item -Force -confirm:$false` as well as `Remove-Item -Force -ea 0` to no avail.  (PS -ea 0 is short for -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)  Thanks!

```
Get-ChildItem -Path e:\myfolder -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-29) } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: I'm confused. You say that you don't want ANY dates below the top-level folders to be considered, but then you say that you don't want to `-Recurse`ively delete the top-level folders? Can you clarify, and provide an example?

Comment: e:\myfolder\folder1 (is 30 days old) and contains e:\myfolder\folder1\subfolder1 (which is 2 days old).  If I recurse, it will leave subfolder1, won't it since it's not old enough to be deleted? I don't want that - I want the entire folder1 deleted.  The reverse is also common for me, in that the subfolders are sometimes older than the top level parent, but have to stay for x days - these folders are basically deployment packages with files of varying dates.

Comment: If you recurse on `e:\myfolder\folder1`, then everything beneath it will be removed. What you're trying to do requires the `-Recurse` parameter.

Comment: You want the `-Recurse` on the Remove-Item, which would recursively remove items. It doesn't care about some subfolder being 2 days old, we're past that point in the pipe where it's looking at age.

Comment: You are correct.  I just tested it.  This works perfectly.  Thank you so much!